# Who first used the cross-ratio to describe shapes in hyperbolic geometry?

Tags: reference-request, gt.geometric-topology, ho.history-overview, hyperbolic-geometry

I was reading this Wikipedia article today:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shape#Similarity_classes
and I realized that it strongly resembles the use of coss-ratios as "shape parameters" in hyperbolic geometry.

I wanted to add material to the article related to this; however, I would like to add a reference concerning the origin of the cross-ratio in hyperbolic geometry.

Who was the first person to use the cross-ratio to parametrize shapes in hyperbolic geometry?

Comment: I think its use in projective geometry predates the conformal models for hyperbolic geometry, meaning that its origin lies elsewhere, and somebody worked it into the Poincare disc and upper half plane along the way. So Beltrami or Poincare, maybe even Weierstrass. There is a book on sources in hyperbolic geometry, one of the authors visits MO sometimes.

Answer (score 7):

I've hesitated to attempt an answer to this question because
I do not know about shape parameters. However, in the hope that 
what is really wanted is a history of the cross-ratio, here goes.

The cross-ratio, and its invariance under projection, was discovered
by Pappus and rediscovered by Desargues around 1640. It appears in
Proposition 129 of Book VII of Pappus' *Mathematical Collection* from 
around 300 CE. The Desargues version appears in a 1648 book called
*Mani`ere universelle de Mr Desargues* written by Desargues' disciple
Abraham Bosse.

It became standard in projective geometry when the subject flourished
in the 19th century. It was used by Cayley in his "Sixth memoir on 
quantics" of 1859 (which was *not* his thesis) to introduce a metric
into projective geometry. In 1871, Klein realized that this metric
was in fact the metric for the hyperbolic plane in his paper "Ueber
die sogenannte Nicht-Euclidische Geometrie."

Answer (score 2):

Thurston (even before his [lecture series](https://library.slmath.org/nonmsri/gt3m/) in 1979) was probably the first to use cross-ratios to describe the shapes of hyperbolic tetrahedra.  He was certainly the first to use these shapes to compute the hyperbolic volume of knot complements.

Answer (score 0):

Yuri Burman once told me that this was introduced in Cayley's thesis.  He conjectured that this must have been the shortest thesis in the history of math as all of the groundwork had been laid.

Comment: Do you a link for Cayley's thesis or even the title? Math genealogy is little help here: http://genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu/id.php?id=7824